# How can I use the path from gulp.src() in gulp.dest()?

Tags: gulp, less, gulp-less

Trying to create a gulp task that will pipe a bunch of files from different folders through LESS and then output them to a folder based on the original source. Consider this folder structure:

```
Project
+-- /Module_A
|   +- /less
|   |  +- a.less
|   +- a.css
|
+-- /Module_B
    +- /less
    |  +- b.less
    +- b.css
```

Here's my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var less = require('gulp-less');

gulp.task('compileLess', function () {
  gulp.src('./*/less/*.less')
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest( ??? ));
});

gulp.task('default', ['compileLess']);
```

I know gulp.dest() expects a path to be passed in but in my example the path will be different based on the source file. So how can I grab the path from source, modify it and then pass it into gulp.dest()?

Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Given your example input, what should the output be?  Gulp uses the relative file paths (based on the first glob pattern) to determine output directory.

Comment: If the input is `Project/Module_A/less/a.less`, I want the output to be `Project/Module_A/a.css`. I was able to accomplish using gulp-rename plugin.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should have a look at [gulp-rename](https://github.com/hparra/gulp-rename)

Pretty much:

```
gulp.src('./*/less/*.less')
  .pipe(less())
  .pipe(rename(function(path){
    // Do something / modify the path here         
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./finalRootDestination'))
```

You leave gulp.dest pointing at your final output dir, but modify on the fly the individual file paths based on whatever logic you want inside the callback to gulp-rename.

Comment: Can you please further explain how you obtained that? I'm using rename plugin but can't figure out how to obtain: "img/jquery-prettyPhoto/images/prettyPhoto/image.jpg" to output in "img/prettyPhoto/image.jpg". How do i remove those 2 useless folders? thanks

Comment: @pwnjack : did you read the documentation of `gulp-rename` I linked?

Comment: Ofcourse i did, otherwise i wouldn't have asked here. Can you please explain how to get rid of the folders, or at least set an absolute output path? thanks

Comment: Read the doc buddy! It clearly explains how to manipulate `dirname`, and this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I like CoryDorning's answer better - then you don't even have to do an extra pipe.  It looks like this is what the src() base option was designed for.

Answer (score 87):

in your `src` set the `base` option and it will maintain the original path of your less file.

```
gulp.task('compileLess', function () {
  gulp.src('./*/less/*.less', {base: './'})
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(gulp.dest( './dist' ));
});
```

The `./dist` destination can be anything. Wherever you want your file structure to be placed.

Additional info here:
https://github.com/wearefractal/glob-stream#options

Comment: The keyword `base` gave me the wrong idea. This is the solution I was looking for.

Comment: Adding in `, {base: './'}` was crucial.

Comment: But it will create a folder inside `./dist` named `less` and then put the file there. How do I specify that I want to exclude the 'less' folder and put the file there?

Comment: This is way neater than the accepted answer. Many thanks :)