# Gulp.js - Output files with variable directory names but with a constant filename

Tags: gulp

Given the following input files in `src/`, how do I output the files on the `dist/` folder?

```
Project
+-- src
|   a.md
|   b.md
+-- dest
|   a/index.html
|   b/index.html

// Gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const md = require('gulp-markdown');

gulp.task('md', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
    .pipe(md())
    .pipe(gulp.dest( // help ))
})
```

I think this is not a duplicate of 
[Gulp.js - Use path from gulp.src() in gulp.dest()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240977/gulp-js-use-path-from-gulp-src-in-gulp-dest). That question deals with variable directory names *and* variable filenames. This question deals with variable directory names *but* with a constant filename.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the gulp-rename plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename

You could use a function for name mapping:

```
const rename = require('gulp-rename');

...

gulp.task('md', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
    .pipe(md())
    .pipe(rename((path) => {
      path.dirname += "/" + path.basename;
      path.basename = "index";
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'))
})
```

Comment: @AnanthRao's answer is more modular. +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

Using [gulp-if](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-if):

**Run**

```
npm install gulp-if --save-dev
```

**Your task**

```
// Gulpfile.js
const gulp = require('gulp');
const md = require('gulp-markdown');
const gulpif = require('gulp-if');

gulp.task('md', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
    .pipe(md())
    .pipe(gulpif('a.md', gulp.dest('dest/a')))
    .pipe(gulpif('b.md', gulp.dest('dest/b')));
})
```

**Alternative**

Using the else part of gulp-if, shorter but less readable

```
gulp.task('md', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/**/*.md')
    .pipe(md())
    .pipe(gulpif('a.md', gulp.dest('dest/a'), gulpif('b.md', gulp.dest('dest/b'))));
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry. this is wrong. This will output
    +-- dest
    |   a.html
    |   b.html
instead of
    +-- dest
    |   a/index.html
    |   b/index.html

Comment: @JohnPatrick, I misunderstood the question. I think you can just use gulp-if for conditional destinations. I will change the answer to reflect an example.